# undefined symbol when linking several shared objects

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I have a linkage problem with GCC that is driving me nuts. My knowledge in this area is a bit cobbled together (from google) and improvised, so I am sure it's my fault but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Hopefully someone can put me out of my misery.

Here is a simplified version of the problem.

I have a static library stat.a which has a function called A(). This is a third party lib so I don't know how it was compiled exactly.
Running nm on this library results in:

```
nm -C stat.a
...
00000001 T A()
         U A()
..
```

I am assuming that A is defined in one .o file and is used in another .o both in the same archive. So far so good.

Now I am building a shared object that contains some new object files which use A() and linking that against stat.a using -Wl,--whole-archive (just in case). The result is dyna.so

Third step is building a new shard object called problem.so which has code that uses A() and uses -ldyna when linking.

When linking i get the following:

```
error: undefined reference to 'A()'
```

Running nm on dyna.so results in:

```
...
00028bf8 t A()
...
```

Which means (to my understanding) that it's there but not externalized.

So,

1. Am I right in my assumptions (about extern and local)?
2. Is what I am trying to do supposed to be possible?
3. Assuming 1&2 and true - what should I do to solve this?

Thanks in advance, much appreciated.